# What are smart data sources in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I wanted to know what data sources can be called 'smart' in spark. As per book "Mastering Apache Spark 2.x", any data source can be called smart if spark can process data at data source side. Example JDBC sources.

I want to know if MongoDB, Cassandra and parquet could be considered as smart data sources as well?

Comment: Your question is too generic. I don't think there is any classification that clearly buckets databases/datasources into Smart vs Non-Smart datasources.

Answer (score 1):

I believe smart data sources can be those as well. At least according to slides 41 to 42 you can see mention of smart data sources and logos including those sources (note that mongodb logo isn't there but I believe it supports the same thing https://www.mongodb.com/products/spark-connector, see section "Leverage the Power of MongoDB") from the Databricks presentation here: https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/bdtc2

I was also able to find some information supporting that MongoDB is a smart data source, since it's used as an example in the "Mastering Apache Spark 2.x" book:

"Predicate push-down on smart data sources Smart data sources are those that support data processing directly in their own engine-where the data resides--by preventing unnecessary data to be sent to Apache Spark.

On example is a relational SQL database with a smart data source. Consider a table with three columns: column1, column2, and column3, where the third column contains a timestamp. In addition, consider an ApacheSparkSQL query using this JDBC data source but only accessing a subset of columns and rows based using projection and selection. The following SQL query is an example of such a task:

select column2,column3 from tab where column3>1418812500

Running on a smart data source, data locality is made use of by letting the SQL database do the filtering of rows based on timestamp and removal of column1. Let's have a look at a practical example on how this is implemented in the Apache Spark MongoDB connector"